# What should i use instead of get.userId to get the username of the facebook user?

Tags: java, android, facebook, methods

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private LoginButton loginButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "MAGNETOB.TTF");
        TextView myTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview1);
        myTextview.setTypeface(myTypeface);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {


            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                System.out.println("Facebook Login Successful!");
                System.out.println("Logged in user Details : ");
                System.out.println("--------------------------");
                System.out.println("User ID  : " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
                System.out.println("Authentication Token : " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login Successful!" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  *** // Over here where it says get.UserId()***

            }


            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login cancelled by user!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Facebook Login failed!!");



            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login unsuccessful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("Facebook Login failed!!");
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(reqCode, resCode, data);
    }
```

In my onSucess method i want to print the username using toast but cant seem to find how to do so without textview which isnt what i want, i want to load the username using toast but currently im loading the userID.

Please help thanks

Comment: you can´t get the username anymore, since v2.0 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Answer (score 1):

- ### Inside the onSuccess method tried this:

  ```
      @Override 
  public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) { 

    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    if(profile != null) {    
     String fbid = profile.getId();
              String name = profile.getFirstName();
              String profileUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + fbid
                                      + "/picture?type=large";         }

  }
  ```
  -

### The Other way to do is using graph

```
    @Override
            public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject json, GraphResponse response) {
                        if (response.getError() != null) {
                            //show error message to user
                        } else {
                            loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions();
                            Log.d("fb response", json.toString());
                            try {
                                //check json response
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email,gender, birthday,location");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();

            }
```

Comment: Nope didnt work also i want to just have the username in the toast part if thats possible

Comment: Have you passing this permission:
 LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));

Comment: Gives me a problem when it comes to the JSON exception and also the access token

Comment: check this link out ive screenshot it

Link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/gv1rxec13p5zlt5/Picture1.png?dl=0

Comment: the the first solution gave me this problem

link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojpcj9n4zrzikva/Picture3.png?dl=0

Comment: check the update answer . Also check the screen shot https://www.dropbox.com/s/ojpcj9n4zrzikva/Picture3.png?dl=0 here you are adding an extra semi colon at the end of fbId remove that one and try.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onSuccess` method use Graph API for getting user info see [official doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile)

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

     Bundle params = new Bundle();
     params.putString("fields", "id,name,first_name,last_name");//here you can add more fields as you want 
     new GraphRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), "me"/*you can also  pass FB id of user instead of 'me'*/, params, HttpMethod.GET,
     new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            if (response != null) {
                try {

                      JSONObject userObj = response.getJSONObject();
                      String fname =userObj.optString("first_name");
                      String lname =userObj.optString("last_name");
                      String fullName =userObj.optString("name");

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
     }).executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: its red underlines saying cant be defined

Comment: have you added Facebook SDK in your project ?

Comment: Yea ofc without that no aspect fb related would work

Comment: Heres a screenshot of it :

Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fatme8xml0drh8h/Picture2.png?dl=0